# How to use youtube embed in my application,now its going to youtube site

Tags: java, android, youtube, embed

Actually i am getting url from json,now in my listview its shows all the list of youtube url which was there in json parsing.After clicking the url it is going to youtube page and that video is playing,I dont want to go to othersite from my application,the video has to be shown in my applicaiton,for that how i will use youtube embed in my application.

**How to show the listof youtube videos in my listview,now it showing the url,I want it has to show the small videos of listview if we click the video it will play the youtube video in my apps using embed**

Myactivity.java

```
public class PoojaVideos extends Activity implements FetchDataListener1  {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    ListView lv2;
    private List<Application1> items;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item1);  

        lv2 =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listV_main);   
        lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv2.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Application1 obj_itemDetails = (Application1)o;
                final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(((Application1) o).getUrlWiki()));
                  startActivity(i);


            } 
        });

        //praycount.setOnClickListener(this);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView(){
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://www.ginfy.com/api/v1/videos.json";
        FetchDataTask1 task = new FetchDataTask1(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application1> data) {
        this.items = data;
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter1 adapter = new ApplicationAdapter1(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        lv2.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } This is the activity for showing listview and after clicking the item in list it is going to youtube page.
```

mylayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

     <ListView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listV_main"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I dont want to go in youtube site,the video has to show in my application itself,for that how to use embed

Application Adapter.java

```
public class ApplicationAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<Application1> {

    private List<Application1> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    private PoojaVideos activity;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ApplicationAdapter1(PoojaVideos context, List<Application1> items){
        super(context, R.layout.activity_row1, items);
        this.items = items;
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        activity=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        //View v = convertView;
        if ( convertView == null ){ 
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_row1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.prayersLinkWiki = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prayersLinkWiki);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }





        Application1 app1 = items.get(position);

        holder.prayersLinkWiki.setText(Html.fromHtml(app1.getUrlWiki()));



        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView prayersLinkWiki;

    }
    //return convertView;



}
```

Fetchdatatask1.java

```
public class FetchDataTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private final FetchDataListener1 listener;
    private  OnClickListener onClickListener;
    private String msg;

    public FetchDataTask1(FetchDataListener1 listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        if ( params == null )
            return null;
        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];
        try
        {
            // create http connection
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            // connect
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            // get response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if ( entity == null )
            {
                msg = "No response from server";
                return null;
            }
            // get response content and convert it to json string
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            msg = "No Network Connection";

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sJson)
    {
        if ( sJson == null )
        {
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // convert json string to json object
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sJson);
            JSONArray aJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray("youtube_url");
            // create apps list
            List<Application1> apps = new ArrayList<Application1>();
            for ( int i = 0; i < aJson.length(); i++ )
            {
                JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                Application1 app1 = new Application1();
                 app1.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+json.getString("youtube_url"));



                // add the app to apps list
                apps.add(app1);



            }
            //notify the activity that fetch data has been complete
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
        }
        catch ( JSONException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            msg = "Invalid response";
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function will convert response stream into json string
     * 
     * @param is
     *            respons string
     * @return json string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null )
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

this is for the row url showing layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prayersLinkWiki"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:autoLink="web"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my listview it will shown the url,after clicking the url it goes to youtube site for video,for the listview in holder url can we use embed for list of youtube videos in this line `holder.prayersLinkWiki.setText(Html.fromHtml(app1.getUrlWiki()));`

Answer (score 0):

Remove The Code `final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(((Application1) o).getUrlWiki()));
                  startActivity(i);` add code to open a dialog with webview. In the webview load youtube URL

Comment: Can we do like this,in holder it showing the url,i dont want to show the url incase of url ,can we show the youtube videos one by one  by using embed

Comment: can you see my code and tell,actually now it showing all the url in my listview i want to show the small small videos of url having in my listview,if we click it has to play the video

Comment: How to use the webview in my code to load the url after removing those lines

Comment: @R world,how to use the webview in my code,have you seen my code and requirement,for that what i wan to do

Comment: are you there dude,how to use webview